# How to create VS Code extension to show and update data via REST API

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to an create extension, which shows data fetched from REST service in editor so user would able to edit it and on save, i should able to call REST service to update data.

Scenario:

1. Create custom in extension
2. On view load, call REST API to showlist of country on explore
3. When user select country from explore, call REST API to fetch list of Cities and show data is edit view.
4. If user update data, on save, call REST API to update data.

Any thoughts or sample ?

Comment: Start from [`Extending Visual Studio Code`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/overview) and work your way up from there.

Comment: Thanks for info...! I'm able to do step #1 and #2(where i'm able to load tree from JSON data but for #3, i want to show data in editor. when i tried below command, its downloading JSON file instead of showing JSON data in editor. vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.openFile', filePath => vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.open', vscode.Uri.parse(`http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/all`)));  Any ideas ?